# Background-image transition not woking in Firefox (-moz-)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I dont get the fade of the background picture to work in Firefox but any other Browser. Help is appreciated!

Just click on the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click_me").click(function(){
        $('.click_me').css('background-image', 'url(https://placekitten.com/500/500)');
    });
});
```

```css
.click_me {  
height:500px;
width:500px;
opacity: 1.0;
background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/500);
-webkit-transition: background-image 700ms linear;
-moz-transition: background-image 700ms linear;
-o-transition: background-image 700ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-image 700ms linear;
transition: background-image 700ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click_me"></div>
```

Comment: Background-image is not transitional, however, Chrome recently added the fade effect but this is not an expected behavior and it is not mentioned anywhere in the specs. Don't rely on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using *jQuery* already why don't use its `animate` function instead of *CSS transitions*, this will do the trick for you very easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click_me").one('click', function() {

    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 'fast', function() {
      $(this)
        .css({
          'background-image': 'url(https://placekitten.com/500/500)'
        })
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.click_me {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/500/500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click_me"></div>
```